# How can this query be optimized for speed?

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

This query creates an export for UPS from the deliveries history:

```
select 'key'
,      ACC.Name
,      CON.FullName
,      CON.Phone
,      ADR.AddressLine1
,      ADR.AddressLine2
,      ADR.AddressLine3
,      ACC.Postcode
,      ADR.City
,      ADR.Country
,      ACC.Code
,      DEL.DeliveryNumber
,      CON.Email
,      case 
       when CON.Email is not null
       then 'Y' 
       else 'N' 
       end 
       Ship_Not_Option
,      'Y' Ship_Not
,      'ABCDEFG' Description_Goods
,      '1' numberofpkgs
,      'PP' billing
,      'CP' pkgstype
,      'ST' service
,      '1' weight
,      null Shippernr
from   ExactOnlineREST..GoodsDeliveries del
join   ExactOnlineREST..Accounts acc
on     ACC.ID = del.DeliveryAccount
join   ExactOnlineREST..Addresses ADR 
on     ADR.ID = DEL.DeliveryAddress
join   ExactOnlineREST..Contacts CON 
on     CON.ID = DEL.DeliveryContact
where  DeliveryDate between $P{P_SHIPDATE_FROM} and $P{P_SHIPDATE_TO}
order  
by     DEL.DeliveryNumber
```

It takes many minutes to run. The number of deliveries and accounts grows with several hundreds each day. Addresses and contacts are mostly 1:1 with accounts. How can this query be optimized for speed in Invantive Control for Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this query is run at most once every day, since the `deliverydate` does not contain time. Therefore, the number of rows selected from `ExactOnlineREST..GoodsDeliveries` is several hundreds. Based upon the statistics given, the number of accounts, deliveryaddresses and contacts is also approximately several hundreds.

Normally, such a query would be optimized by a solution such as [Exact Online query with joins runs more than 15 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112801/exact-online-query-with-joins-runs-more-than-15-minutes), but that solution will not work here: the third value of a `join_set(soe, orderid, 100)` is the maximum number of rows on the left-hand side to be used with index joins. At this moment, the maximum number on the left-hand side is something like 125, based upon constraints on the URL length for OData requests to Exact Online. Please remember the actual OData query is a GET using an URL, not a POST with unlimited size for the filter.

The alternatives are:

1. Split volume
2. Data Cache
3. Data Replicator
4. Have SQL engine or Exact Online adapted :-)

## Split Volume

In a separate query select the eligible `GoodsDeliveries` and put them in an in-memory or database table using for instance:

```
create or replace table gdy@inmemorystorage as select ... from ...
```

Then create a temporary table per 100 or similar rows such as:

```
create or replace table gdysubpartition1@inmemorystorage as select ... from ... where rowidx$ between 0 and 99
... etc for 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
```

And then run the query several times, each time with a different `gdysubpartition1`..`gdysubpartition5` instead of the original from `ExactOnlineREST..GoodsDeliveries`.

Of course, you can also avoid the use of intermediate tables by using an inline view like:

```
 from (select * from goodsdeliveries where date... limit 100)
```

or alike.

## Data Cache

When you run the query multiple times per day (unlikely, but I don't know), you might want to cache the Accounts in a relational database and update it every day.

You can also use a 'local memorize results clipboard `and`local save results clipboard  to `to save the last results to a file manually and later restore them using`local load results clipboard  from ...`and`local insert results clipboard  in table `. And maybe then`insert into  from exactonlinerest..accounts where datecreated > trunc(sysdate)`.

## Data Replicator

With Data Replicator enabled, you can have replicas created and maintained automatically within an on-premise or cloud relational database for Exact Online API entities. For low latency, you will need to enable the Exact webhooks.

## Have SQL Engine or Exact adapted

You can also register a request to have the SQL engine to allow higher number in the join_set hint, which would require addressing the EOL APIs in another way. Or register a request at Exact to also allow POST requests to the API with the filter in the body.